# Reducing a list to the sum of the differences of its elements

Tags: list, common-lisp, reduce

I have a simple list with an always even number of integers like

```
(42 38 15 5)
```

and I want to calculated the total sum of the difference of its pairs, i.e.

```
(+ (- 42 38) (+ 15 5)) --> 14
```

It could be 2, 4 or more elements but it will always be an even number. I thought there would be a way using reduce for this but I do not see a way to get the pairs right.

Is there a simple way to do this or is it easier to change the list structure? E.g to something like

```
((42 38) (15 5))
```

Comment: When you say "equal number" do you mean "even number"?

Comment: @lioness99a Sorry, just edited the wrong wording.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `loop` for this:

```
(loop :for (a b) :on list :by #'cddr
      :sum (- a b))
```

The `for`-`on` construction goes over the tails of the list, `for` can destructure that, `by` gives the stepping function (default `#'cdr`).

If you absolutely want to use higher order functions, you need to either partition first (as you already surmised) or find a stepping mechanism.

Partitioning can again be done through `loop` or through cons-fiddling.  Afterwards, you could reduce:

```
(reduce (lambda (sum pair)
          (+ sum (apply #'- pair)))
        (partition 2 list)
        :initial-value 0)
```

Alternatively, you could think about it as alternatingly adding and subtracting a number:

```
(reduce #'+
        (mapcar #'funcall
                (circular-list #'+ #'-)
                list))
```

(`Circular-list` is from `alexandria`.)

Comment: Hmm, that's too easy ;-) I was somehow stuck in thinking about mapping/reducing.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extension of your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a shorter loop:

```
(loop 
   while list 
   sum (- (pop list)
          (pop list)))
```